# Deleting files and folder older than 3 days via batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script to delete files and folders that have data older than 3 days. But there are files inside the folder and once the files are deleted, the folder's last modified data changes to today which is causing the folder not to get deleted.

My script has 3 different files:

#### 1. Property file that consists of paths and time

```
path_3=D:\Scripts\DeleteLogsScripts\test,3
```

#### 2. Batch file to read the path and time and send them as variables to another batch file

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims==," %%G IN (data.properties) DO (
@echo %%G %%H %%I
set local_path=%%H
set local_time=%%I
call backup_filecheck1.bat !local_path! !local_time!
)
```

#### 3. Batch file to delete files

```
set local_path=%1
echo %local_path%
set local_time=%2
Forfiles /P "%local_path%" /S /D -%local_time% /C "Cmd /C If @isdir==FALSE Del @Path"
Forfiles /p "%local_path%" /S /C "Cmd /C If @isdir==TRUE RD /s /q @Path 2>Nul"
```

The folder it is deleting from:

[image: Oroginal Folder Structure]

[image: After the files are deleted]

As you can see, the folder's last modified date changes to today.

I am not understanding how to tackle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did finally figure out how to do it. I updated the script in such a way that after deleting the files, it'll sort files and delete empty folders

`set local_path=%1 echo %local_path% set local_time=%2 Forfiles /P "%local_path%" /S /D -%local_time% /C "Cmd /C If @isdir==FALSE Del @Path" cd /D %local_path%\%%a for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%i">NUL`